# how to calculate sum of times in mysql database query in cakephp

Tags: mysql

In cake php i have written query like

```
$d = $this->Bill->find('all',array('fields' => array('sum(Bill.totaltime)   AS ctotal'),'conditions' =>array('Bill.pid =' => $pid)));
```

in my database i have times like

```
10:20:00
05:55:00
```

according to the query i am getting the output as

```
  15:75:00
```

i need to get the output like this

```
 16:15:00
```

how to write the query to get the out put as the following please help me on writing query to get output like this.

Comment: What type of field is totaltime? (int? date? timestamp?)

Comment: it is of type 'time'

Comment: it is of data type time ,,,can u help me over this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $d = $this->Bill->find('all',array('fields' => array('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(Bill.totaltime) ) )   AS ctotal'),'conditions' =>array('Bill.pid =' => $pid)));
```

Please check this